# Beeline query with SSL (Hive missconfiguration ? )

Tags: hadoop, ssl, hive, kerberos, beeline

I am triying on a cluster that have Kerberos to make a beeline query works :

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://server_hive.server.lan:10000/default;principal=hive/server_hive.server.lan@COMPTES.RACINE.LOCAL;AuthMech=1;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/opt/cloudera/security/jks/cm.truststore;trustStorePassword=XXXXX" -e "show databases"
```

But I get this error :

```
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://server_hive.server.lan:10000/default;principal=hive/server_hive.server.lan@COMPTES.RACINE.LOCAL;AuthMech=1;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/opt/cloudera/security/jks/cm.truststore;trustStorePassword=XXXXX
Unknown HS2 problem when communicating with Thrift server.
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://server_hive.server.lan:10000/default;principal=hive/server_hive.server.lan@COMPTES.RACINE.LOCAL;AuthMech=1;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/opt/cloudera/security/jks/cm.truststore;trustStorePassword=XXXXX: Peer indicated failure: GSS initiate failed (state=08S01,code=0)
No current connection
```

I really don't know what's wrong. it's working on an other cluster, but not on this one. The Hive log say that :

```
[HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-43]: SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)]
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Server.evaluateResponse(GssKrb5Server.java:199)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport$SaslParticipant.evaluateChallengeOrResponse(TSaslTransport.java:539)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:283)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory$1.run(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory$1.run(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:790)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory.getTransport(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:790)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:269)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:856)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Server.evaluateResponse(GssKrb5Server.java:167)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: KrbException: Checksum failed
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType.decrypt(ArcFourHmacEType.java:102)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType.decrypt(ArcFourHmacEType.java:94)
    at sun.security.krb5.EncryptedData.decrypt(EncryptedData.java:175)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(KrbApReq.java:281)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(KrbApReq.java:149)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(InitSecContextToken.java:108)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:829)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.security.GeneralSecurityException: Checksum failed
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.ArcFourCrypto.decrypt(ArcFourCrypto.java:408)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmac.decrypt(ArcFourHmac.java:91)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType.decrypt(ArcFourHmacEType.java:100)
    ... 23 more
May 18, 2:28:08.319 PM  ERROR   org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer  
[HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-43]: Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: GSS initiate failed
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory$1.run(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory$1.run(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:790)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory.getTransport(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:790)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:269)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: GSS initiate failed
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.sendAndThrowMessage(TSaslTransport.java:232)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:316)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
    ... 10 more
```

What could generate the checksum failed please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after some research, an hive load balancer was set. so when a load balancer is set, it listen only to the virtual IP and you can't no more ask directly to the Hive server.

So if you set the Virtual IP, you have to query the VIP, no other hosts.

Or you have to remove the VIP to be able to query directly the Hives servers.

Answer (score 0):

can you please do as follow

1. enter

**beeline** in bash

2. enter

!connect jdbc:hive2://server_hive.server.lan:10000/;principal=hive/server_hive.server.lan@COMPTES.RACINE.LOCAL

to see it is asking for **username** please